# mixing openssl API and BSD sockets API

Tags: c, sockets, unix, openssl, portability

I'm writing a client that must deal with both ordinary http protocol and also https for secure connections. For ordinary http connections, I should use basic socket I/O functions such as send(), recv() and so on. But for https connections, I should use SSL_read(), SSL_write and other functions from the OpenSSL library. Currently I use the following approach:

```
if (isHTTPS)
{
    /* use OpenSSL calls */
    SSL_write();
}
else
{
    /* use basic socket I/O functions */
    send();
}
```

But I think this is not a good way, as it is not easy to code this way. Any suggestion on this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the *traditional* API model for using OpenSSL.  An `SSL` object owns the socket and performs all I/O on it, so you have to use the `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()` functions when performing secure I/O.

OpenSSL also has a *newer* API model using `BIO` structures instead.  You can create a `BIO` object for a socket and then associate an `SSL` object with it only when you need secure I/O, and then use `BIO_...()` functions (`BIO_read()`, `BIO_write()` etc) to handle the actual I/O.  In secure mode, the `BIO` functions will use the `SSL` functions internally for you:

```
bio = BIO_new_connect(...); // host/IP and port
if (IsHTTPS)
    BIO_set_ssl(bio, ssl, ...);

// alternatively:
if (IsHTTPS)
{
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(sslCtx);
    BIO_set_connect_hostname(...); // host/IP and port
    ...    
}
else
    bio = BIO_new_connect(...); // host/IP and port

BIO_do_connect(bio);
...    

BIO_read(bio, ...);
...    

BIO_write(bio, ...);
...    

BIO_free(bio);
```

This BIO API is also the one you would use if you want to perform your own socket I/O (ie, for overlapped/asynchronous sockets), letting OpenSSL handle just the security for it.  You would create a `BIO` that links two memory buffers together.  You can then read inbound data from your socket into one buffer and have OpenSSL consume it using `BIO_read()`, and write outgoing data using `BIO_write()`.  Any outgoing data that OpenSSL generates will be put in the other buffer, which you can then write to your socket as needed.